# Layer 'conv2d_11' expected 2 variables, but received 0 variables during loading. Expected: ['conv2d_11/kernel:0', 'conv2d_11/bias:0']

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, loading

I wanted to load a model using tf.keras.models.load_model('ACM1_9035P.keras') as I usually do but all of a sudden this time it wouldn't load. I got the error message seen in the title. This method has worked many times before but this time it didn't. What's the problem and how can I fix it?

I can provide more information about the model and system if needed.

I used google colab to train, save and load the model.
The model was saved using model.save()
The model is saved a .keras file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer:

The model was created and saved using TensorFlow version 2.13.0

I was trying to load it using TensorFlow version 2.14.0

Downgrading the version in Google Collab to 2.13.0 allowed me to load the model as I have done before.

To see how you can change the TensorFlow version in Collab, check out this page:

https://gist.github.com/mervess/5efbec9f62a55a4cd47c900999db7927

Comment: This helps. But do you know how I can make the .keras file compatible with the latest version so that I do not always have to downgrade the version when I relaunch the notebook?

Comment: I believe the TensorFlow team have not solved that issue yet from what I have found on some forums.

Answer (score 5):

Loading keras model in a newer keras/tf version is a big headache. From my experience, you can save the model in a few formats that keras provides, and hopefully one of the formats will work cross-version. It depends on the specific source and target versions.

The formats keras provides also depend on version, for 2.14 they are (can also be set using the `save_format` input arg to `keras.models.save_model`):

1. "tensorflow" format, use `.tf` file extension
2. "keras" format, use `.keras` file extension
3. "hdf5" format, use '.h5' file extension
4. "checkpoint" format, in which you load the model's architecture from code, and load the weights from disk using `model.load_weights` method. Note that here as well you need to choose format, between `hdf5` and `tensorflow`.

So, for example, saving a model in keras 2.14 and loading in 2.15, doesn't work if you use `keras` format, but does work for `h5` and `tf` formats. So just experience and see.

**Please read the docs** as there are some important details when saving and loading (for example, saving the optimizer, custom layers, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I have also encountered a similar kind of problem. When I created or saved(tensorflow 2.13.0) the model with the **.keras** extension the same day, I was able to load the model. but now I encountered the below error:

***Error loading the model: Layer 'conv2d' expected 2 variables, but received 0 variables during loading. Expected: ['conv2d/kernel:0', 'conv2d/bias:0']***

isn't it wiered that is due to different version of the tensorflow library.

I do not see any change in the API though https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/saving/load_model